# In VBA, trying to replace all times (in a string) with another time, ie: all xxxxCST to (xxxx + 0100)EST

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet full of times in CST times where a single cell contains xxxxCST-xxxxCST (for example 1000-1100CST). I want to use VBA to replace all times in CST with EST, thus adding 1 hour. In the above example that would be 1100-1200EST (I'm using 24 time format).

I thought this would be a find and replace type solution, and have tried using excel wild cards where ? is any one character so that I find anything with four characters and CST (????CST) to replace it with something, but cannot figure out how to add the 0100 hr since the ????CST I think is a string and I would have to find the CST item first, separate the numerical part, then add the 0100 then recombine, etc. I may be going about this the wrong way, but ultimately would like to replace all xxxxCST to (xxxx + 0100)EST and similarly if this was in a word document rather than excel replace all xxxxCST to (xxxx + 0100)EST.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could look at using regex - plenty of previous posts on how to use that in VBA.  https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+regex+replace+site:stackoverflow.com   Or if your values are all xxxx-yyyyCST then it would be pretty straightforward to pull it apart with Left/Mid/Right, make the adjustments, then re-combine.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process is correct.  You need to pull the string apart, make needed adjustments and then recombine.  Here is some code to illustrate how this would be done:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Debug.Print Add1Hour("1000-1100CST")
End Sub

Private Function Add1Hour(ByVal Time As String) As String
   Dim pieces As Variant
   Dim startTime As Integer
   Dim endTime As Integer
   
   pieces = Split(Time, "-")
   startTime = CInt(pieces(0)) + 100
   endTime = CInt(Left(pieces(1), 4)) + 100
   Add1Hour = startTime & "-" & endTime & "EST"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the value as true time values:

```vb
CstTime = "1000-1100CST"
Parts = Split(CstTime, "-")

StartTime = DateAdd("h", 1, TimeValue(Format(Val(Parts(0)), "00\:00")))
' 11:00:00 
EndTime = DateAdd("h", 1, TimeValue(Format(Val(Parts(1)), "00\:00")))
' 12:00:00 

EstTime = Format(StartTime, "hhnn\-") & Format(EndTime, "hhnn\E\S\T")
' 1100-1200EST
```